# how to use less with create-react- app after using eject?

Tags: reactjs

I just did `npm run eject` but less file is still not compiling for me.

Can someone explain what I should modify or add to the Webpack config file? or maybe I need to modify the webpackdevserverconfig.js file instead?

I cannot find test: `/\.css$/` in the configuration file anywhere. Did I do something wrong?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const resolve = require('resolve');
const PnpWebpackPlugin = require('pnp-webpack-plugin');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const CaseSensitivePathsPlugin = require('case-sensitive-paths-webpack-plugin');
const InlineChunkHtmlPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/InlineChunkHtmlPlugin');
const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');
const safePostCssParser = require('postcss-safe-parser');
const ManifestPlugin = require('webpack-manifest-plugin');
const InterpolateHtmlPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/InterpolateHtmlPlugin');
const WorkboxWebpackPlugin = require('workbox-webpack-plugin');
const WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/WatchMissingNodeModulesPlugin');
const ModuleScopePlugin = require('react-dev-utils/ModuleScopePlugin');
const getCSSModuleLocalIdent = require('react-dev-utils/getCSSModuleLocalIdent');
const paths = require('./paths');
const modules = require('./modules');
const getClientEnvironment = require('./env');
const ModuleNotFoundPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/ModuleNotFoundPlugin');
const ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin = require('react-dev-utils/ForkTsCheckerWebpackPlugin');
const typescriptFormatter = require('react-dev-utils/typescriptFormatter');

const postcssNormalize = require('postcss-normalize');

const appPackageJson = require(paths.appPackageJson);

// Source maps are resource heavy and can cause out of memory issue for large source files.
const shouldUseSourceMap = process.env.GENERATE_SOURCEMAP !== 'false';
// Some apps do not need the benefits of saving a web request, so not inlining the chunk
// makes for a smoother build process.
const shouldInlineRuntimeChunk = process.env.INLINE_RUNTIME_CHUNK !== 'false';

const isExtendingEslintConfig = process.env.EXTEND_ESLINT === 'true';

const imageInlineSizeLimit = parseInt(
  process.env.IMAGE_INLINE_SIZE_LIMIT || '10000'
);

// Check if TypeScript is setup
const useTypeScript = fs.existsSync(paths.appTsConfig);

// style files regexes
const cssRegex = /\.css$/;
const cssModuleRegex = /\.module\.css$/;
const sassRegex = /\.(scss|sass)$/;
const sassModuleRegex = /\.module\.(scss|sass)$/;

// This is the production and development configuration.
// It is focused on developer experience, fast rebuilds, and a minimal bundle.
module.exports = function(webpackEnv) {
  const isEnvDevelopment = webpackEnv === 'development';
  const isEnvProduction = webpackEnv === 'production';

  // Variable used for enabling profiling in Production
  // passed into alias object. Uses a flag if passed into the build command
  const isEnvProductionProfile =
    isEnvProduction && process.argv.includes('--profile');

  // We will provide `paths.publicUrlOrPath` to our app
  // as %PUBLIC_URL% in `index.html` and `process.env.PUBLIC_URL` in JavaScript.
  // Omit trailing slash as %PUBLIC_URL%/xyz looks better than %PUBLIC_URL%xyz.
  // Get environment variables to inject into our app.
  const env = getClientEnvironment(paths.publicUrlOrPath.slice(0, -1));

  // common function to get style loaders
  const getStyleLoaders = (cssOptions, preProcessor) => {
    const loaders = [
      isEnvDevelopment && require.resolve('style-loader'),
      isEnvProduction && {
        loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
        // css is located in `static/css`, use '../../' to locate index.html folder
        // in production `paths.publicUrlOrPath` can be a relative path
        options: paths.publicUrlOrPath.startsWith('.')
          ? { publicPath: '../../' }
          : {},
      },
      {
        loader: require.resolve('css-loader'),
        options: cssOptions,
      },
      {
        // Options for PostCSS as we reference these options twice
        // Adds vendor prefixing based on your specified browser support in
        // package.json
        loader: require.resolve('postcss-loader'),
        options: {
          // Necessary for external CSS imports to work
          // https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/2677
          ident: 'postcss',
          plugins: () => [
            require('postcss-flexbugs-fixes'),
            require('postcss-preset-env')({
              autoprefixer: {
                flexbox: 'no-2009',
              },
              stage: 3,
            }),
            // Adds PostCSS Normalize as the reset css with default options,
            // so that it honors browserslist config in package.json
            // which in turn let's users customize the target behavior as per their needs.
            postcssNormalize(),
          ],
          sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
        },
      },
    ].filter(Boolean);
    if (preProcessor) {
      loaders.push(
        {
          loader: require.resolve('resolve-url-loader'),
          options: {
            sourceMap: isEnvProduction && shouldUseSourceMap,
          },
        },
        {
          loader: require.resolve(preProcessor),
          options: {
            sourceMap: true,
          },
        }
      );
    }
    return loaders;
  };
```